# the usage of comma is "appositive" or not

Tags: appositives

> We had two departments, the Department of English and the Department of Mathematics.

In this sentence, I can't decide the usage of comma is "appositive" or not. I don't think it is not appositive structure as it says only the lists,not the quality.

Comment: It looks like a supplementary appositive construction to me.

Answer (score 1):

Aye, it is.
*The Department of English and the Department of Mathematics.* refers back to the *two departments* adding value to the sentence.
It's not just listing the departments, it's also telling you the names which is a valuable info.